# Warp Matrix-Multiply functions - are single-precision multiplicands supported?

Tags: cuda, precision, matrix-multiplication, cuda-wmma

In the [CUDA Programming guide, v11.7, section B.24.6. Element Types & Matrix Sizes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma-type-sizes), there's a table of supported type combinations, in which the multiplications are either sub-single-precision floating point types, or `double` - never `float . But - in [section B.24.1 Description](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma-description), it says that:

> The data type, T [for matrix fragments], may be double, float, __half, __nv_bfloat16, char, or unsigned char for multiplicands and double, float, int, or __half for accumulators.

So, can the multiplicand matrices be `float`, or can't they?

Answer (score 2):

**Probably not**, single-precision floating-point multiplicands are not supported.

The [PTX ISA guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) lists the lower-level WMMA primitives and their different operand combinations, in [Section 9.7.13](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#warp-level-matrix-instructions); and, indeed, there are *no* primitives where single-precision floating-point (`f32`) can be the data type of the multiplicand matrices. The closest we can get is [`tf32`](https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2020/05/14/tensorfloat-32-precision-format/) for the multiplicands,  and `f32` for the addend and the result. Now, if PTX doesn't have the primitives we're after, it is all but impossible that they exist on the actual micro-architectures and are simply not exposed (and the compiler will not be able to optimize other PTX code into fp32 WMMA).

Note that double-precision multiplicands *are* supported (although YMMV when it comes to their speed).

---

**edit:** This answer may need some qualification. A 2020 [NVIDIA blog post](https://blogs.nvidia.com/blog/2020/05/14/tensorfloat-32-precision-format/) about TF32 says:

> TF32 Tensor Cores operate on FP32 inputs and produce results in FP32. Non-matrix operations continue to use FP32.

So, if you can pretend your multiplicands are TF32 (and I'm not sure you actually can), then, in a sense, single-precision floating-point is usable, though the accuracy may be lower than expected.